# Indexes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I've a collection that occupies 1.7 GB and 13.7m documents with the following format:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61765c68713f1d0ae2a0765a"
    },
    "x": 0.0658416748046875,
    "y": -1.668808937072754,
    "z": 9.654911994934082,
    "timestamp": {
        "$numberLong": "1635146850481"
    },
    "id": "Alice",
    "mac": "0004",
    "activity": "Work"
}
```

I'm trying to make distinct/aggregate queries which take 8 to 13 seconds, for the use that will be given to the database they are very slow.

I've tried to create indexes, simple and compound, all of text type, but they don't give me good results, it increases the time of the query up to 30s (I understand that it is because the indexes are not well chosen).

Can the indexes be repeated?, for example I've created an index with the `id` field, but there are 100 thousand documents where the `id` is the same, is this correct?

I am in a test environment that has 4GB of RAM but in production is mounted the same machine with Replica Set.

I don't know if it is necessary to increase the RAM (I imagine it is), change the way data is stored, change the indexes or everything.

Comment: Please show us your aggregation pipeline!

Comment: This query takes ~7s `db.col.distinct("activity",  {"id": "Alice"},  {"mac": "0004"} )`

Comment: And where are your indexes?

Comment: I never used `distinct` operation, however I would assume `db.col.distinct("activity",  {"id": "Alice",  "mac": "0004"} )`

Comment: the last one I've tried is: `[name: 'TextIndex', 'weights: { activity: 10, id: 5, title: 1 }}]` and the query `db.col.aggregate([ {$group: {_id:null, sett: {$addToSet: "$activity}}}], {hint:"TextIndex"})`  takes 40s

Comment: Again, which indexes did you create? And what is the expected result?

Comment: If there are 100 thousand documents where the id is the same then indexing that field probably will have no effect and that index will never used (or used very rarely).
Distinct values are useful for indexes, you may organize your data differently, for example having a field like "idmac": "Alice0004" and index that field.
If possible prevent running distinct at all, store necessary distinct values in another, smaller collection collection: `{"idmac": "Alice004", "distinctactivity": ["work", "xxx", ...]}`